# bash with /r/n problem

Tags: bash, sed

```
echo "enter date"
read -e date  <===2011 年 7 月 11 日
dateRecent=$(sed 's/?* 年/ 年\r\n/g' <<< $date)
echo $dateRecent
```

the output is 7 月 11 日

```
check='2011 年/r/n 7 月 25 日'
echo $check
```

the output is nothing, can't echo

```
dateRecent='$dateRecent'
```

the output is `$dateRecent`

So, my question is , why is that and how to make the first input same as the second one???
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `echo -e` to enable backslash-escaped characters in `echo`. For example:

```
check='2011 年\r\n 7 月 25 日'
echo -e "$check"
```

Use double-quotes not single quotes, otherwise variables will not get expanded.

```
foo="$dateRecent"
```